# Reset java certifications (on linux) due to Maven download issue

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, keystore

I am using Ubuntu Linux 15.10. A few days ago I cloned a small git project which is using Maven (I use version 3.3.3). After cloning I wanted to use the

```
mvn install
```

command to download all dependencies but an error occurred. Using the same command with the -X parameter shows the problem in detail:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext): Invalid keystore format -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.3
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:298)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:131)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.3
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
... 26 more
....
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:767)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:733)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
... 83 more
```

I checked if my JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/) is set correctly and deleted my ~/.keystore file. I generated a new one with the keytool -genkey command. Afterwards I reinstalled ca-certificates-java and ca-certificates. But nothing helps.

If I use the command

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I get the following error:

```
org.debian.security.InvalidKeystorePasswordException: Cannot open Java keystore. Is the password correct?
at org.debian.security.KeyStoreHandler.load(KeyStoreHandler.java:68)
at org.debian.security.KeyStoreHandler.<init>(KeyStoreHandler.java:52)
at org.debian.security.UpdateCertificates.<init>(UpdateCertificates.java:65)
at org.debian.security.UpdateCertificates.main(UpdateCertificates.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1226)
at org.debian.security.KeyStoreHandler.load(KeyStoreHandler.java:66)
... 3 more
```

It seems that there is an general problem with the keystore on my linux system. Maven install for this projects works on others systems.

Could anybody help me fixing this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: I would not bother trying to fix it, but simply reinstall java.

Comment: you might want to try and check `java.home/jre/lib/security` folder. There is `cacerts` file there. `ls -laF cacerts` .  It should be soft-linked to `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`. If it's not you can try and link it: `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts java.home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: cacerts exists and is linked to /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

Comment: Reinstalling Java (JDK) or reinstalling certs didn't fixed the problem. Can I reset the password or should I reinstall my complete linux system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed the issue with by purging and reinstalling ca-certificates-java using the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

Maybe this could help anybody in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by @vivid works,if just in case that does work
If you did not change the file cacerts,you can update it simply by reinstalling your JDK or copying it from another installation.

Comment: Tried to do as you suggest but it hadn't helped. Vivid's solution worked just fine